# Display multiple google maps within an ajax success

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    // include foundation clearing first so it's available later
      $.getScript('/static/js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js');
      $.getScript('/static/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js');
        $(".compare").each(function(){
          $(this).append("<span class='left open hide-for-small'><i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i><span class='text'>Show more</span></span>");
        });
      $('.compare span.left').on('click', function(e){

        var language = $("html").attr("lang"); 
        e.preventDefault();
          $('.show-more').fadeOut();
          var that = $(this),
            propID = that.parent().parent().data("id"),
            current = that.parent().parent();
          if(that.hasClass('open')){
            current.find('.text').text('Show less');
              that.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
              that.removeClass('open').addClass('close');
              if(!current.hasClass('ajax-called')) {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'+propID, 
                  dataType: 'json', 
                  headers: {  
                    "Accept-Language": language
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    current.addClass('ajax-called');
                    current.css('padding-bottom', '56px');
                    });
                    // *******************************************************map******************************************************
                    current.find('.thumbs-holder').after("<div id='m-" + $(current).data('id') + "'></div>");
                    var myLatLngCurrent = {lat: parseFloat(data.latitude), lng: parseFloat(data.longitude)};
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("m-" + $(current).data("id")), {
                      zoom: 18,
                      center: myLatLngCurrent
                    });
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: myLatLngCurrent,
                      map: map,
                      zoom: 10
                    }); 
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                  }, cache: false
                });
              }
          }
          else {
            current.css('padding-bottom', '.5rem');
            that.removeClass('close').addClass('open');
            current.find('.show-more').fadeOut();
            that.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
                current.find('.text').text('Show more');
          }
      });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fabresult data-id="xxx">
  <div class="compare">
    <span class="left"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I than call it inside an ajax success as follow:

```
                var map;
                var currentMap = new CreateMap(current, data, map);
                currentMap.generateMap();
```

I have a list in my markup and for each "li" I click a make a new ajax call to pull some data in. As part of each call, "CreateMap()" gets called.

The first time I click the map is displayed correctly but after that when I click on a new "li" I only see a gree bakground with the google logo at the bottom left and the correct CSS width property applied to it, but not the new map itself.

THis is what I get when I click the second time:

[image]

Comment: The "m-" + $(current).data("id") element (lias the new map id)  is visible of is hidden before invocation ?

Comment: it's a property id which is different for every "li", I think hidden

Comment: And how do you set visible the related div id?

Comment: by appending it within the current "li": current.find('.thumbs-holder').after(propertyMapWrapper);

Comment: You should trigger a resize once the element has been shown. `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

Comment: It doesn't work, however I have noticed that when I resize the window the map shows

Comment: When/where did you call the resize? As I said, you should trigger it **once the element has been shown**. This should work. And if it doesn't, update your question with that part of your code too.

Comment: updated with triggerring the resize method

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is called when you click the `li` element. Is that **when it is shown**? Probably not. Is this a custom made list? Do you use any kind of plugin that would provide events? Your question lacks a lot of information.

Comment: No plugins used, I have updated the js and markup to show better how the code is structured